# Mac Pro 2009 8-core not detecting a single RAM memory stick

Tags: mac, memory, macos-mojave

I'm a video editor working in a small team.

My workstation is a Mac Pro 2009 8-core 2.66 GHz 24GB RAM (Mojave 10.14.6). 24GB RAM used to be enough time ago before we updated Premiere and After effects. Now, the RAM it's not enough and the MAC happens to freeze and crash at once per week.
My co-worker and me thought about expanding the RAM. We have an unused Mac Pro 2012 wich uses the same RAM specs but it's 2x8GB. We tried filling the two empty slots in the 2009 machine but Mac deactivated one 4GB stick and another 8GB stick, resulting with 28GB total. We moved the 8GB sticks back to the other Mac and re-arranged the original RAM sticks until the red LEDs were no longer active.

The result: Now, it only detects 5 out of 6 memory sticks, wich is equal to 20GB RAM.
What is going wrong? If the LED is not on, it means it is detected and in the correct place, but it's not being detected.

Comment: On phone so can’t search & link. Check you have the RAM in the right slots. Check if it’s the slot or the RAM that’s not working.

Comment: @Tetsujin they're in the correct slots as the guide says. I don't think it's a slot problem as it detects when an incorrect ram it's placed in there